# Redefine a method

Tags: c#

I have a class A which holds a collection of objects. Every instance of the class fills the collection according a different logic. From time to time I need to update all the collections. 
I was thinking this could be done maybe if the class has a method that holds the logic for filling the collection and I can set this logic at the time of the creation of the object. 
Like this:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();

instance.updateCollection = { logic for filling the collection } //
```

The logic will be different for each object.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this easily with an [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx).

Either pass yor desired `Action` in the constructor, or make a property that allows you to set the desired `Action`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should be using something like a Factory which creates these objects, but stores a reference to them as well. You can then have a separate method inside your factory to update each collection inside the factory.

Also - don't constrain yourself to one class. If you embrace the ideas of polymorphism and inheritance instead of fighting them, you'll find C# a lot easier and more fun.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using Action class:

```
class MyClass
{
  private readonly Action<List<string>> _updateAction;

  private readonly List<string> _collection = new List<string>();

  public MyClass(Action<List<string>> updateAction)
  {
    _updateAction = updateAction;
  }

  public void Update()
  {
    _updateAction(_collection);
  }
}


class MyClassTester
{
  public static void Test()
  {
    MyClass weekdayAdder = new MyClass(c => c.Add(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString()));
    MyClass timeAdder = new MyClass((c) => c.Add(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()));

    weekdayAdder.Update();
    weekdayAdder.Update();

    timeAdder.Update();
    timeAdder.Update();
    timeAdder.Update();
  }
}
```